# When I encounter an audit, can I write anything into the custom flag box?

Tags: support, review, flags, review-audits

When I review posts and encounter an audit, and I've confirmed that it's an audit that wants me to flag/downvote/close the post *(by opening the actual question in another tab)*, is it a free ticket to write *anything* into the "in need of moderator intervention" flag box, for example "I had oatmeal for breakfast.", and nobody will *ever* see it?

Why would I bother writing anything if it will just disappear into cyberspace? I don't know.

I've tested whether I can see the message I put before *(I wouldn't be posting this question if I haven't)*, and I couldn't find it. But that doesn't mean that the staff and/or mods cannot see them.

Again, my question is: Would what I write into the box make an impact *at all*, or I can write *literally* anything, and *nobody* will see it?

Would the custom message be *submitted*, or would it be deleted on the spot?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by the "custom flag box".  Which queue are you talking about?

Comment: @Sonic I think they mean: they encounter a "known bad" audit, where raising a flag would be a way to pass it. On that situation, choosing a flag of "in need of moderator intervention", and if whatever you write there is significant, is stored anywhere or whatnot.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog Oh, I'm sorry! I hope my edit clears things up.

Comment: @Glorfindel I believe this applies to close and downvote situations too.

Comment: Not for downvotes (you do pass the audit then, but you can't type anything). Custom close reasons: yes, that would be possible. Since you were talking about 'custom flag box' I assumed it didn't apply to close votes.

Comment: @Glorfindel I mean, it doesn't matter whether we downvote, close or flag such an audit, they will still say congrats.

Comment: If you downvote to pass the audit, you can't flag it anymore.

Comment: @Glorfindel *and I've confirmed that it's an audit that wants me to flag/downvote/close the post* means that I went over to the actual post before taking any action.

Comment: Sure, feel free to roll it back, it's your post after all.

Comment: I must say, this is the first time I've ever gotten the "Hooray, this question was reopened!" message. I thought it was a comment at first.

Comment: You could write anything, but the only people who will see the full data are the diamond moderators, if that's what you're asking...but I doubt you'll pass ;)

Comment: @Ollie Pass? You know, I'd be more interest to find out the someone can see it, rather than it being deleted instantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. I tested it [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/227658), where I flagged the question for moderator attention:

[image]

but the flag was nowhere to be found in my flagging history.

Also, voting to close a question with a custom off-topic reason, as I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/27497270), does not produce a comment:

[image]

It's the same as for downvoting an audit (or upvoting a positive audit); those votes aren't really cast. I've analyzed the network traffic when you do so; there is no POST call to `/flags/.../add` which what normally happens when you cast a flag; only a call to `/review/task-reviewed/...` which happens after finishing every review task. So, yes, everything you type there is safe and nobody will see it.

(In case you're wondering what the teapot is for: see the [Mozilla developer documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/418).)

Comment: I tested it too, but that isn't necessarily enough. Perhaps the staff can see them, or they are kept in a cyber garbage can that authorized people can access?

Comment: Yeah, it *might* be logged somewhere but nobody is going to pay attention to it.

Comment: That's my question. Of course it might, but I want to know the exact answer.

Comment: One definitive check would be if the AJAX call for the close-vote is actually sent to SE. If the data is never sent to SE, then there will be no record of it. If it is sent, then there *might* be a record of it.

Comment: @Makyen good point, I've just checked it and there's no such call.

Comment: When I did a review (a suggested edit, and not an audit; as it happened) I used a custom close reason and it *did* show up were **we** can see it, example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76119 --- Ann's question is about reviews in general, and where she has figured out that it's an audit beforehand; ultimately if audits discard the custom reason. If it's not an audit (you guess wrong) the message is definitely visible. -- Having reviews that simply won't be sending the custom reason makes them easier to differentiate from non-audit reviews, and subject to roboreviewing.